# changing the working-directory of command from java

Tags: java, command-line, batch-file, working-directory

I need to execute a .exe file from a function in one of the packages I have in my java project. now the working directory is the root directory of the project for java but the .exe file in sub-directories of my project. here is how the project is organized:

```
ROOT_DIR
|.......->com
|         |......->somepackage
|                 |.........->callerClass.java
|
|.......->resource
         |........->external.exe
```

Initially I tried to run the .exe file directly through:

```
String command = "resources\\external.exe  -i input -o putpot";
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process pr = rt.exec(command);
```

but the problem is external .exe needs to access some files in it's own directory and keeps thinking root directory is its directory. I even tried to use .bat file to solve the problem but the same issue rises:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"cmd.exe", "/c", "resources\\helper.bat"});
```

and the .bat file is in the same directory as the .exe file but the same issue happens. here is the content of the .bat file:

```
@echo off
echo starting process...

external.exe -i input -o output

pause
```

even if I move .bat file to root and fix its content the problem does not go away. plz plz plz help

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To implement this you can use the ProcessBuilder class, here's how it would look like:

```
File pathToExecutable = new File( "resources/external.exe" );
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( pathToExecutable.getAbsolutePath(), "-i", "input", "-o", "output");
builder.directory( new File( "resources" ).getAbsoluteFile() ); // this is where you set the root folder for the executable to run with
builder.redirectErrorStream(true);
Process process =  builder.start();

Scanner s = new Scanner(process.getInputStream());
StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
while (s.hasNextLine()) {
  text.append(s.nextLine());
  text.append("\n");
}
s.close();

int result = process.waitFor();

System.out.printf( "Process exited with result %d and output %s%n", result, text );
```

It's quite a bunch of code, but gives you even more control on how the process is going to be run.

Comment: it looks reasonable but I cannot believe there is no simpler method to achieve the intended result

Comment: I know it's an old question/answer, but I really think the second most voted answer should be accepted over this one (the one saying to use the form of exec which takes 3 arguments).  As the commenter above said, this is reasonable code but it's more complicated than necessary if all you want is to change the working directory.

Comment: I use this Runtime.exec("bash", "-c", "cd <yourdir>; your command")

Answer (score 19):

Use [this form of the `exec` method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29) to specify a working directory

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray,
                    String[] envp,
                    File dir)
             throws IOException
```

The working directory is the third argument. You can pass `null` for `envp` if you don't need to set any special environment.

There's also [this convenience method](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File%29):

```
public Process exec(String command,
                    String[] envp,
                    File dir)
             throws IOException
```

...where you specify the command in one string (it just gets turned into an array for you; see the docs for details).

Answer (score 1):

I goted a same problem in my project, I tryed this solutions about `ProcessBuilder.directory(myDir)` and the exec method from `Runtime` and all my trays failed.. 
It's make me understanding that the `Runtime` have a limited privileges just for the working directory and the sub directories of it. 
 
So my solution is ugly but working very well. 
I create a temporary .bat file in "runtime" in the working directory. 
This file included two lines of commands:  
1. Move to needed directory (cd command). 
2. Do the command in need. 
I call the exec from `Runtime`  with my temporarily .bat file as command. 
It's work for me very well!