# execute file from defined directory with Runtime.getRuntime().exec

Tags: java, shell, exec

I just want to execute my file from a specific folder. in my case /data/data/my-package/files/.
So i tried :

```
 Process process2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cd /data/data/my-package/files/");
 process2.waitFor();
 process2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./myfile");
```

It doesn't work. could anyone tell me please the right way to do that . Thanks

Comment: does `....exec("/data/data/my-package/files/myfile");` work?

Comment: it work but here i want to exec my file from specified folder because it generate a new file. thanks

Comment: You can see [my answer][http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811522/changing-the-working-directory-of-command-from-java/42281455#42281455]

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It should be possible to call the executable with a specific working directory using [`Runtime.exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File))

as follows:

```java
Process process2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/data/data/my-package/files/myfile",
        null, new File("/data/data/my-package/files"));
```

maybe without the full path to `myfile`

```
Process process2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myfile",
        null, new File("/data/data/my-package/files"));
```

`Context#getFilesDir()` instead of hardcoding the path should work too and is safer / cleaner than specifying the path yourself since it is not guaranteed that `/data/data/..`
is always the correct path for all devices.

```
Process process2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myfile",
        null, getFilesDir()));
```

The problem with `cd somewhere` is that the directory is changed for a different Process so the second call to `exec` in a new Process does not see the change.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me when I use the following overloaded method:

> **public Process exec(String command,
>              String[] envp,
>              File dir)**

For example:

```
File dir = new File("C:/Users/username/Desktop/Sample");
String cmd = "java -jar BatchSample.jar";
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd, null, dir);
```

The command just stores the command you want to run in command line. `dir` just stores the path of your .jar file to be executed.

Answer (score 0):

A different solution will be,

Execute a .bat file from the Java Code

And do all the directory change, and stuff inside the bat file

For instance, my execute.bat file looks like this,

```
cd flutter_app
flutter build apk
cd ..
```

And the Java code looks like this,

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("execute.bat");
```