# Java system cannot find file specified when trying to execute

Tags: java, file, directory

I want to execute an array of commands in my dir. When I hit `cd C:/Users/Lennart/sciebo/Semster 2/Info/RepoCreator/Abgabe 4` into the command line it works fine.
But when I execute the follwing code I am getting a FileNotFoundException, because "System cannot find the file specified".

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec(getCMDs());

    ...

    private static String[] getCMDs() {
        String cd = "cd C:/Users/Lennart/sciebo/Semster 2/Info/RepoCreator/Abgabe " + index;
//      String cd = "cd " + path + "/Abgabe " + index;
        String init = "git init";
        String add = "git add .";
        String commit = "git commit -m \"Inital commit\"";

        return new String[] {cd, init, add, commit};
    }
```

I tried to use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(getCMDs(), null, file)` with the required changes. File was `File file = new File("C:/Users/Lennart/sciebo/Semster 2/Info/RepoCreator/Abgabe 4");` Loading the file was not a problem and also System.out.println(file.exists()); was true, but executing the array led to the same error.

Thank you

EDIT:

Yes, I tried the overloaded methode as described above. Here is the code:

```
File file = new File(path + "/RepoCreator/Abgabe 4");
        System.out.println(file.exists());
        try {
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(getCMDs(), null, file);
...

    private static String[] getCMDs() {
        String init = "git init";
        String add = "git add .";
        String commit = "git commit -m \"Inital commit\"";

        return new String[] {init, add, commit};
    }
```

Unfortunally this does not make a difference.

Comment: It looks you need to quote the filename containing spaces:  `String cd = "cd \"C:/Users/Lennart/sciebo/Semster 2/Info/RepoCreator/Abgabe " + index + "\"";`

Comment: That does not change it :/

Comment: Did you try using overloaded version of exec https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)

Comment: Yes, as I described above

Comment: If you are using the exec() with File, you should omit the `cd` variable. It means that you are already going to that dir and then trying to do `cd` again which does not exist

Comment: separate "git", "init"  into 2  elements

Comment: @JavaTechnical what do you mean?

Comment: See my updated answer. It is not just with `git` but also if you try to run `notepad myfile.txt`, then we get error, however if it is like String st[]={"notepad", "myfile.txt"}, the next element is taken as an argument for the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to execute git commands in the specified directory.

You can try using an overloaded version of the [exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[],%20java.lang.String[],%20java.io.File)) method:

```
public Process exec(String[] cmdarray,
           String[] envp,
           File dir)
```

Here is an [example on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10690899/2534090) (snippet below)

```
Process process2=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("myfile",
    null, new File("/data/data/my-package/files"));
```

**Edit:** In your `getCMDs()` omit the `cd` command again when using this `exec()` method.

```
return new String[] {"git","init"};
```

and then execute the next command with its arguments.

I think we need to pass each argument as a separate array element because when executing `notepad myfile.txt` I would have to do..

```
String st[] = { "notepad", "myfile.txt"};
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(st,null,new File("D:/test dir/"));
```

So you could also do something like

```
String st[] = {"git","init"}
```

See the following [gist](https://gist.github.com/Crydust/fd1b94afc52cd0f7dd4c)

Comment: From what you've posted, you are trying to `cd` again i.e. the `getCMDs()` is returning the the `cd` command also.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you note this but you are missing the last letter '4' ->
"cd C:/Users/Lennart/sciebo/Semster 2/Info/RepoCreator/Abgabe 4"

If it is just a typo, maybe you can try using double bar, by example:

```
 C:\\Users\\Lennart\\...\\
```

Comment: Index is equals 4. \\ or / does not make a difference

Answer (score 0):

Don't you have to escape the slash characters?