# Incorrect *.bat execution from Java

Tags: java, batch-file

I have .bat file with following content for example:

```
mkdir testDir
```

Now I put it to folder C:\temp
Then I want to run it using java so I do following:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\temp\\test.bat");
```

I expect that folder will be created in C:\temp like when I execute this file manually, but folder is being created in my workspace which is wrong.
How can I fix it?

Comment: Specifically, the [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6811578/474189) in that duplicate is likely the best and matches Jon's answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the working directory when you run `cmd`.

There are overloads of `Runtime.exec()` which allow you to specify a working directory. For example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start C:\\temp\\test.bat", null,
                          new File("c:\\temp"));
```

Alternatively, you can use [`ProcessBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to give rather more explicit control of various aspects of the process you're starting.