# When Runtime.getRuntime().exec call linux batch file could not find its physical directory

Tags: java, bash, processbuilder, pwd

I have an java application.And I use Runtime.getRuntime().exec for call a batch file.When I call a linux batch file using with Runtime.getRuntime().exec the batch file could not find its own directory.
I use pwd command in batch file but it returns application path.
I need batch file's own  physical path from itself.
How can I do this?

Comment: You should use `$0` rather than `pwd` but that’s not in any way related to Java. It might be even belong to http://superuser.com/ rather than stackoverflow.

Comment: `batch` file for `Linux` is generally called `script` in Linux!

Comment: or if you want to change the working dir look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811522/changing-the-working-directory-of-command-from-java

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59895/can-a-bash-script-tell-what-directory-its-stored-in

Answer (score 4):

You must use a [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) in order to acomplish that:

```
ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder( "pathToExecutable");
builder.directory( new File( "..." ).getAbsoluteFile() ); //sets process builder working directory
```

Comment: +1 for the correct, cross platform, solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try this . Its working for me.

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("pwd");
        BufferedReader bri = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader bre = new BufferedReader
                (new InputStreamReader(p.getErrorStream()));
        String line;
        while ((line = bri.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bri.close();
        while ((line = bre.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
        bre.close();
        p.waitFor();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Batch files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Batch_file), if you're specifically referring to files with the '.bat' extension, are designed to be used with Microsoft's Command Prompt shell ('cmd.exe') in Windows, as they are script files containing a sequence of commands specifically for this shell, and as such will not work with Unix shells such as Bash.

Assuming you actually mean a Unix 'shell script', and not specifically a Microsoft 'batch file', you'd be better off using the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class, as it provides greater flexibility than Runtime's `exec()` method.

To use ProcessBuilder to run a script in its own directory, set the builder's directory to the same directory that you're using to point to the script, like so:

```
// Point to wherever your script is stored, for example:
String script    = "/home/andy/bin/myscript.sh";
String directory = new File(script).getParent();

// Point to the shell that will run the script
String shell = "/bin/bash";

// Create a ProcessBuilder object
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(shell, script);

// Set the script to run in its own directory
processBuilder.directory(new File(directory));

// Run the script
Process process = processBuilder.start();
```