# How to run .exe file in java

Tags: java, exe

I know it has been asked before, but none of those answers seem to work for me. I am trying to get a .exe file running in a java program. The following code (that I plucked from Internet) works; Notepad starts.

```
import java.io.IOException;

public class start {
   public static void main(String args[])
   {
       try {
           Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe"});
       } catch (IOException e) {
           // TODO Auto-generated catch block
           e.printStackTrace();
       }
   }

}
```

But when I change the folder to the one that contains my own .exe file, it doesn't do anything. It doesn't even give an error. It just starts and terminates. If I double-click the file in the folder itself, it just opens and runs, so the file itself works.

So, just to be clear, I changed `Process p` to

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"C:\\Users\\Sharonneke\\Documents\\IntraFace-v1.2\\x64\\Release\\IntraFaceTracker.exe"});
```

Why won't this work and how do I fix it?

Update:
So I don't have to use the `new String []` but that doesn't solve the problem. Also, using the ProcessBuilder (like kage0x3b said in the answer section) gives the error: `"The constructor ProcessBuilder(String) is undefined"` while it apparently should work like that :(

Comment: Can you try running the file from the command line to make sure that works? Press [Windows Key]+R, type "cmd", hit enter, copy the full path to the exe in the cmd window, and see if it runs or gives you relevant error information

Comment: It gives an error indeed: |
Error opening model file "DetectionModel-v1.5.bin"!
FaceAlignment cannot be initialized.

Comment: Check if you have to run it as an administrator

Comment: By right-clicking it and then clicking "run as administrator"? That just works. But normally double-clicking worked as well.

Comment: It doesn't work. I still get the same error.

Comment: @Sharonneke95 so what is "DetectionModel-v1.5.bin"? How is that supposed to be fed to the program?

Answer (score 2):

You dont need an array for only one application to be run...

just do:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
```

and add the respective `try catch` block

---

using a **processBuilder**

```
ProcessBuilder p = new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Windows\\System32\\notepad.exe");
p.start();
```

Comment: This seems to not change anything :( Notepad works, my own doesn't

Comment: I already try with my own c# app as .exe and worked just fine.... are you executing a valid file??? can you start it by doubleClicking or in the CMD???

Comment: With double-click it starts. In CMD it won't :s

Comment: For the ProcessBuilder-part, I get this error: "The constructor ProcessBuilder(String) is undefined"

Comment: o-0? check if the ProcessBuilder is the correct one... class: ***java.lang.ProcessBuilder.ProcessBuilder***

Comment: I think so. I import 'java.lang.ProcessBuilder' and then create the object 'ProcessBuilder'. That's okay, right?

Comment: You're right! I can delete it, it doesn't change anything. Learned something :) Tnx!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there is a problem with the working directory of the program if it tries to load files from the  working directory which obviously works if clicked but I think not when executed from Java code if you do not set it.
Try using a ProcessBuilder and then setting the working directory:

```
    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Sharonneke\\Documents\\IntraFace-v1.2\\x64\\Release\\IntraFaceTracker.exe");
    ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(file.getAbsolutePath());
    processBuilder.directory(file.getParentFile());

    try {
        processBuilder.start();
    } catch(IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: You beat me to it. OP's question looks a lot like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811522/changing-the-working-directory-of-command-from-java

Comment: I cannot run it because of this error: "The constructor ProcessBuilder(String) is undefined"

Comment: Maybe you are using the wrong ProcessBuilder class (it should be java.lang.ProcessBuilder as ΦXoce 웃 Пepeúpa said. There certainly is a constructor with a String argument.

Comment: I am calling the right class apparently. I'll restart my computer once. That sometimes works when everything else fails, right? Haha

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your help, but unfortunately none of your answers worked. I managed to find something that runs my code well enough (according to my supervisor, that is) so I'm happy. This is what I'm using right now:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Users\\Sharonneke\\Documents\\IntraFace-v1.2\\x64\\Release\\IntraFaceTracker.exe", null, new File("C:\\Users\\Sharonneke\\Documents\\IntraFace-v1.2\\x64\\Release\\"));
```

For some reason this works even though it wouldn't when I used it like before, but I decided to not ask questions anymore. It works :)
Thanks again for taking your time to try and help me!

Comment: Why are you creating new file directory in your code?

Comment: I don't know. It worked  so I was happy. I found it somewhere else online :3

Comment: Ok ! I was also having the same problem. Somehow My `exe` started working. But sometimes it does not being started by java code.