# Compile and run a Java program from another Java program

Tags: java, javac

I am writing a program that takes the path to the input ".java" file with a main method. The program should then compile that file, and run it.

Let's say that the program I am trying to compile and run looks like this:

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello, world!");
    }
}
```

The program that performs compilation and tries to run it:

**Evaluator.java**

```
    /**
     * Matches any .java file.
     */
    private static final PathMatcher matcher = FileSystems.getDefault().getPathMatcher("glob:**.java");

    private static String path;

    /**
     * Program entry point. Obtains the path to the .java file as a command line argument.
     * 
     * @param args One argument from the command line: path to the .java file.
     * @throws Exception 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length != 1) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Expected exactly one argument from the command line.");
        }

        if (!matcher.matches(Paths.get(args[0]))) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    String.format("File %s is not a valid java file.", args[0]));
        }

        // path is in a valid format
        path = args[0];

        // compile a program
        compile();

        // run a program
        run();
    }

    /**
     * Compiles a program.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static void compile() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Compiling the program ...");

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac " + path);
        output("Std.In", p.getInputStream());
        output("Std.Out", p.getErrorStream());
        p.waitFor();

        System.out.println("Program successfully compiled!\n");
    }

    /**
     * Runs a program.
     * 
     * @throws Exception
     */
    private static void run() throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Executing the program ...");

        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java " + getProgramName(path));
        output("Std.In", p.getInputStream());
        output("Std.Out", p.getErrorStream());
        p.waitFor();

        System.out.println("Program finished!");
    }

    private static void output(String stream, InputStream in) throws IOException {      
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in, CS));

        for (String line = reader.readLine(); line != null; line = reader.readLine()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s: %s", stream, line));
        }
    }

    private static String getProgramName(String path) {
        return path.replace(".java", "");
    }
}
```

My "Main.java" file is located in the project root. I am running the program with a command line argument "./Main.java". Doing so, compiles the program correctly and yields a new file "Main.class". However, the `run` method outputs as follows:

**Std.Out: Error: Could not find or load main class ..Main**

What should be the problem here?

Comment: Try to pass the file as `Main.java` instead of `./Main.java`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem here is you are passing argument

```
./Main.java
```

instead, you should pass `Main.java` as an argument else you need to change your `getProgramName()` method to return the Class name correctly.

Which will let you compile the program perfectly with `javac` command but problem happens when you need to run the program because that command should be

```
java Main
```

whereas you are trying to execute

```
java ./Main
```

Comment: But you have to give it the path to the program, right? What if the program is not in the project root, but for example in "./data/Main.java"? How should the run command be then?

Comment: Yes you have to but then you need to change your getProgramName() method to return you the correct class name

Comment: What happens if the compiled file is ie in "./data/Main.class"? How do you execute the program then? It should make some difference, no?

Comment: In that case, you need to use `-cp` flag to provide the correct class path and then the class name `java -cp ../somepath../ Main`

Comment: whosoever downvoted, do comment so that I can improve the answer or can remove it. if the answer is not appropriate. But do care to comment

Answer (score 2):

Try to set to java process you're launching the correct working directory and then set the related classpath.

This should help.

**Update**

I suggest to use the method `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(String command, String[] envp, File dir)`.

Last parameter `dir` is the process working directory.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how to do that?

Comment: have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6811522/changing-the-working-directory-of-command-from-java